# Cannot enable/disable clickable TextView inside GridView

Tags: android

I have a GridView with clickable TextViews as GridView items, using an Adapter (the TextViews serve as Buttons). When I click on a TextView, I want to disable all over TextViews in the GridView - disable in the sense that the user cannot click them anymore. What I did is this:

```
    private void toggleButtonsState(boolean enabled)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.gridview.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            this.gridview.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(enabled);            
        }
    }
```

However, even though this code is called with enabled == false, the buttons are still enabled. What wrong here? How can I get the other TextViews disabled? Thanks!

---

I did what you said and implemented BaseAdapter directly. However, again these 2 methods never get called: neither at the beginning nor upon notifyDataSetChanged. Really don't know what's going on. Here is the code:

```
public class TextViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener  {

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.areAllItemsEnabled();
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.isEnabled(position);
}

protected Context mContext;         

public TextViewAdapter(Context c)
{           
    this.mContext = c;      
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return DbManager.getInstance(mContext).getCategoryCount(true);
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {           

    final LinearLayout linearLayout;          

    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_timer_textview, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.timer_textview);           
        textView.setOnClickListener(this);                          

    } else {
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }


    setCategoryView(linearLayout, arg0);    
    setControls(linearLayout, arg0);

    return linearLayout;

}

private void setControls(LinearLayout linearLayout, int index)
{
    TextView textView = (TextView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.timer_textview);
    Category category = getCategory(index);
    textView.setTag(category);                  
    textView.setText(category.getName());            
    textView.setTextColor(TimeManagerActivity.getForeColorByBrightness(category.getColor()));           
    textView.setBackgroundDrawable(createTextViewDrawable(category.getColor()));

    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.timer_checkbox);       
    checkbox.setChecked(category.getEnabled() != 0);        
    checkbox.setTag(textView.getText().toString());
}

protected Category getCategory(int index)
{
    return DbManager.getInstance(this.mContext).getCategoryByIndex(index, true);
}

protected void setCategoryView(View view, int index)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.timer_textview);       
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 40));

    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.timer_checkbox);
    checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0)
{       
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}   

public void update()
{
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private StateListDrawable createTextViewDrawable(int color)
{               
    // Create a gradient for the button. Height is hardcoded to 30 (I don't know the height beforehand). 
    // I wish I could set the gradient aligned to the bottom of the button.
    final Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 0,
        new int[] { color, color },
        null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);          

    float[] roundedCorner = new float[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    ShapeDrawable normal = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(roundedCorner, null, null));

    normal.getPaint().setShader(shader);
    normal.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

    // Create a state list (I suppressed settings for pressed).             
    StateListDrawable state_list = new StateListDrawable();
    state_list.addState(new int[] { }, normal);

    return state_list;
}
```

}

---

Here is my class derived from `TextViewAdapter` which itself is derived from `BaseAdapter`. My `TextViewAdapter` just defines some abstract methods and doesn't do much. The `TextViewApaterMain` tries to disable all TextViews in the Grid except for the one that was clicked on. In `OnClick` I click a TextView and want to disable all other TextViews, so I call `notifyDataSetChanged`, but the overrides `areAllItemsEnabled` and `isEnabled` are not called (debugger doesn't stop at breakpoint). Any ideas? Here's some code:

```
public class TextViewAdapterMain extends TextViewAdapter  {

private ArrayList<Boolean> textViewStates = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

public TextViewAdapterMain(Context c) {
    super(c);


    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return DbManager.getInstance(mContext).getCategoryCount(true);
}

@Override
protected void setCategoryView(View view, int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.timer_textview);       
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 40));

    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.timer_checkbox);
    checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}   

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onClick(arg0);

    ((TimeManagerActivity)super.mContext).launchChronometer((TextView)arg0);


    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
protected Category getCategory(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return DbManager.getInstance(this.mContext).getCategoryByIndex(index, true);
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position)
{                           
    if(textViewStates.get(position))
        return true;

    return false;

}

}
```

Comment: The docs say, "The interpretation of the enabled state varies by subclass."  What are you trying to achieve by having disabled TextViews?  Do you want the touch events to not be handled?  Do you want them to not cycle through drawable states when touched?  Do you want a particular state list drawable state to be applied?

Comment: Note that `getChildCount()` only returns to you the *views that are currently rendered*. Also, since you're only changing the state of whatever is visible, as soon as you scroll and the `getView()` method gets called the state will get reset to whatever it is originally, enabled, presumably.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't work. What you need to do is override two functions in your BaseAdapter class like so:

```
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if(isEnabledData[pos])
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

This also means you will need add a way to your data/model to keep track of selection state, in my example I use a simple boolean[] with true or false. The BaseAdapter will use isEnabled when it draws the grid items to the screen.

If you need to change the state of an item, change to model data isEnable[x] = true/false and then call notifyDatasetChanged() on the adapter.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented both overrides but for some reason, none of them gets called at any time. I put a breakpoint but the code doesn't get called. Again: I have a grid of TextViews that serve as buttons. Once I click on one button, I want ALL OTHER buttons in the grid to be disabled. How do I achieve this?

Thanks again!

Comment: Could you post some more code, like your CustomAdapter class that extends BaseAdapter and possibly what your are doing onClick? I suspect that perhaps your not calling notifyDataSetChanged when you want to change data or have a strange implementation of BaseAdapter.