# Overrides in BaseAdapter with GridView not called by super class

Tags: android

I am starting a new thread based on [Cannot enable/disable clickable TextView inside GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164570/cannot-enable-disable-clickable-textview-inside-gridview/6224147#6224147).

I found out that the overrides isEnabled and areAllItemsEnabled from BaseAdapter will only be called if the Adapter is attached to a ListView, but not to a GridView:

Here these 2 overrides will NOT be called:

```
 gridview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(this));
```

However, here they will be called:

```
 listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(this));
```

So, now back to my original question (see above): How can I toggle the enabled-state of my GridView items (such as enabled/disable TextViews as my items)? Is there a workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I found out that the overrides isEnabled and areAllItemsEnabled from BaseAdapter will only be called if the Adapter is attached to a ListView, but not to a GridView

Correct. While those methods are implemented on `Adapter`, they are a feature of `ListView`, not of `AdapterView`.

> How can I toggle the enabled-state of my GridView items (such as enabled/disable TextViews as my items)?

There is no "enabled-state of my GridView items", AFAIK. If they are in the `GridView`, they are enabled. You are welcome to create your own clone of `GridView` that attempts to implement the stuff you'll find in `lookForSelectablePositionOnScreen()` in the ListView implementation, but this is unlikely to be easy.

I suggest either not putting non-selectable items in the `GridView` in the first place, or settling for visually altering them (e.g., graying them out) and ignoring them if the user taps on them.

Comment: OK yes, that's a good idea. I'll try to grey them out. What's a good way to do this?

Comment: @widi: I was afraid you were going to ask me that... :-) One possibility is to layer a `View` on top of them whose background color is set to a translucent gray value (e.g., `#aaaaaaaa`). If the cells in the `GridView` are `RelativeLayouts`, you could simply add this `View` as the last child of the `RelativeLayout`, so it floats over all the others. Make it be `GONE` from a visibility standpoint until needed. All that being said, there's probably a better answer, but this is what comes to mind off the top of my head.

Comment: Strangely enough, isEnabled is called by the GridView when you click on a cell, but not at any other time. Appears to be only partially supported which is really unfortunate. I have an app where users moves selection around with the keyboard and I am at a loss how to prevent selection from going into certain cells.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to disbale Items/Views in my GridView.

I'm extending a BaseAdapter and added

```
   @Override
   public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    System.out.println("isEnabled?");
    if (position == 0)
        return true;
    return MyPreferences.getInstance(context).isLessonAccessible(validLessons.get(position));
    }
```

The first Entry is always supposed to be enabled, and for every other item im Checking if it is supposed to be enabled. The Method is called every time you click an Item in your GridView. I supposed the same rule applies to a listview as well.